# How to change the port of the service gateway in a logom application?

Tags: lagom

I have created the getting started lagom application  http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/GettingStarted.html

And the system is starting fine.

```
[info] Service locator is running at http://localhost:8000
[info] Service gateway is running at http://localhost:9000
[info] application - Signalled start to ConductR
[info] application - Signalled start to ConductR
[info] Service hellostream-impl listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:26230
[info] Service helloworld-impl listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:24266
```

How do i change the host and port of the service gateway to listen  on 0.0.0.0:8080 ?

Answer (score 5):

1. The hostname seems to be fine. It's possible to access the service from another machine. The `localhost` is hard coded.

   ```scala
   def serviceGatewayAddress: URI = {
       new URI(s"http://localhost:${gateway.address.getPort}")
   }
   ```

   see https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/1.0.0-M1/dev/service-locator/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/discovery/ServiceLocatorServer.scala#L71
2. To configure the port of the service gateway set the property `lagomServiceGatewayPort` in the main `build.sbt`.

   ```
   lagomServiceGatewayPort in ThisBuild := 8080
   ```